# How to hide a Jungle Disk drive for a specific users in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, network-drive, removable-media, jungledisk

This question is related to this question: [How to hide drive for specific users in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7)

What I'm running into on Windows 8 is different than Windows 7. I'm working with Home editions of Windows. In Windows 7 the Jungle disk (Drive K:) is only visible to the admin and not other users. But on Windows 8 it seems to be available even for someone setup up as a child user. I suppose this could be because of a difference in the initial installation of Jungle Disk.

My question is, how can I disable this Jungle Disk Drive, drive K:, which is seen by the computer as removable media in this setup, from a non admin user? I'll achieve my goal if it can be hidden for one particular user.

The second part of the top answer of the previously answered question referenced above may have almost answered my question, but I want to see if it's valid for Windows 8 and I want to see the answer to the following question if the second part of that question is the best solution for moving forward:

I'm wondering how to convert the K: drive to Hexadecimal? According to the scheme it seems like the K: drive should equal b10000000000 which works out to hex 08000000. But this hex is the same as the D: drive in the example given.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Is there a way to "disconnect" a mapped network drive, but NOT remove the mapping?](https://superuser.com/questions/667030/is-there-a-way-to-disconnect-a-mapped-network-drive-but-not-remove-the-mappin):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDrives
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDrives

     Decimal       Hex
A:         1         1
B:         2         2
C:         4         4
D:         8         8
E:        16        10
F:        32        20
G:        64        40
H:       128        80
I:       256       100
J:       512       200
K:      1024       400
L:      2048       800
M:      4096      1000
N:      8192      2000
O:     16384      4000
P:     32768      8000
Q:     65536     10000
R:    131072     20000
S:    262144     40000
T:    524288     80000
U:   1048576    100000
V:   2097152    200000
W:   4194304    400000
X:   8388608    800000
Y:  16777216   1000000 
Z:  33554432   2000000
```

Comment: Thank you. And I suppose that should work for Windows 8?

Comment: @EricMartin, it should.

Comment: Thanks again. I should be trying it and will try to let everyone know what happened at that time.

Comment: I tried going to HKEY_USERS\Foo\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer as per the instructions here: http://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7 I did this both for a Windows 7 and 8 PC. Neither had \Explorer available. So I put the DWORD into \Policies. This process disabled the K: Drive, as desired with my Windows 7 machine but it didn't work for the Windows 8 machine. Any guidance or someone who can confirm that they tried these instructions on Windows 8 would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Worked fine on Win8.1 x64, so I would assume it should work fine on Win8.  Keep in mind that the setting listed is actually part of group policy, and should be set as such.  If you have a conflicting policy applied, it may be overwriting your value.  You also must restart explorer to have the value take effect.

Comment: I restarted it, but the user I'm setting it for is a Child User, so maybe somehow that is overwriting it. Do the new Child Users for Windows 8 create new issues? Thanks.